# Phonegap HTML/Dreamweaver CC Splashscreen

Tags: android, html, xml

I've been reading for the past 2 hours but I can't seem to figure it out.
I've got my 9patch splash image under the directory of res/drawable-*resolution*/splash.9.png

I'm using adobe dreamweaver cc with the built in Phonegap application.  It works fine, but every tutorial I've seen for adding a splash makes use of some Java file, which I do not seem to have.  Here is my layout (the hdpi, xhdpi etc. files in the root are the icons)
[image]

So it seems that phonegap has just added a config.xml and nothing more
My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
id        = "com.phonegap.example"
version   = "0.0.1">

<!-- http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/ awesome tools for icon and background       resizing! -->

<name>Creativity Cards</name>

//icons
<icon src="xxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" />
<icon src="mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />

<description>
Creativity Cards is an idea generator for visual artists.
</description>

<author href="https://www.alexanderlozada.com" email="alexanderpaullozada@gmail.com">
Alexander Lozada
</author>

<preference 
name="exit-on-suspend" value="true"  
name="permissions" value="none" 
/>

</widget>
```

Thanks for any help, this probably simple issue has been slowing driving me to insanity.
I need to know what files to make, and where.  All I start out with is the config.xml and a javascript file seems to fit in somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a Phonegap plugin the splash described [Here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html)

From the plugin install directory, you have to copy manually the Java files to Android source files, because the plugin install not always makes a copy.

I hope it helps!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the plugin install directory?  Where is the Java file I copy?  
I'm not sure if this means anything but Phonegap is integrated with Dreamweaver CC, I didn't install any plugins.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada just click on webpage (link provided), it is explained all there

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being thick, but I've read that before and 5 times over, and it always loses me at 
"In the onCreate method of the class that extends DroidGap add the following two lines:"
No idea what that entails.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada I can't setup your project properly from my desktop... sorry to see it doesn't helping you my answer

Comment: thank you for you input anyway! I'll try moving this to the android overflow and see if I can get an answer.